Programmer vs target clock frequency
I have a 16u2 programming a 1284P for a custom board I am building. The 16u2 converts USB to USART for programming the 1284P, however the 16u2 has a maximum frequency of 16MHZ while the 1284P has a maximum frequency of 20MHZ. I am aiming to use the 20MHZ crystal with the 1284P.
Does the target device(1284P) need to have the same clocking frequency as the programmer(16u2)?

no, it does not

@jsotola You have noticed the "Answer" box on these pages, have you not?

There are multiple ways of programming a 1284P board, such as:

Using the bootloader, via serial input
Using ICSP (via the SPI pins)
High-voltage programming

The bootloader is via a specific baud rate, which is not tied to the processor clock speed. The other two are self clocked so you could probably program them at one byte per second (although you wouldn't want to).

Does the target device(1284P) need to have the same clocking frequency as the programmer(16u2)?

No, it does not.
